# Let $T$ be a tree of order $n$. Why is the complement $\neg T$ of $T$ the same size as $K_{n-1}$?

Tags: graph-theory

I can somewhat understand why it is. But does there exist a proof for this or can it be shown?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the result that every tree of order $n$ has the same size and thus the complements of any trees of order $n$ will be of the same size. Finally, find a particular tree whose complement is $K_{n-1}$ (plus one extra vertex).

Comment: How would I find a particular tree whose complement is $K_{n-1}$ (plus one extra vertex)?

Comment: Try it with some small values of $n$ like 3, 4, 5, and 6. Draw $K_{n-1}$ then add one more vertex with no edges and draw the complement of this graph.

Comment: To "find a particular tree whose complement is $K_{n-1}$ (plus one extra vertex", start with a graph which **is** $K_{n-1}$ plus one extra vertex, and take its complement. (Hint: if you do it correctly, the result will be a kind of tree called a "star".)

Answer (score 0):

Every tree of order $n$ has size $n-1$ (you may want to convince yourself of this). By definition, the complement of a tree on $n$ vertices is a graph on $n$ vertices and $\binom{n}{2}-(n-1) = \binom{n-1}{2}$ edges. The size of $K_{n-1}$ is also $\binom{n-1}{2}$.